# curve_fit from scipy.optimize not working

Tags: python, scipy

I want to make fitting curve with my raw data, but I get such error messages :

```
<ipython-input-6-47cbf1e1c239>:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in true_divide
  return I0*((np.sin(beta)/beta)**2)*(np.cos(gamma))**2
/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:828: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the 
parameters could not be estimated
warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated')
```

Followings are my code and scatter for raw data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sinc(x, b, h, I0, phi):
    beta = 0.5 * b * np.sin(x-phi)
    gamma = 0.5 * h * np.sin(x-phi)
    return I0*((np.sin(beta)/beta)**2)*(np.cos(gamma))**2

                             
data = pd.read_excel('14_laser_doubleslit.xlsx')
display(data)

x = np.array(data.iloc[1:101,0])
y = np.array(data.iloc[1:101,1])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sinc, x, y)
print(popt)
print(pcov)

plt.scatter(x,y,marker='.')
plt.plot(x,sinc(x,*popt),color='blue',linewidth =2)
plt.show
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your `x` and `y` arrays so we can reproduce

Comment: Also, since there is `true_divide` error in `I0*((np.sin(beta)/beta)**2)*(np.cos(gamma))**2` I guess that you should give `beta` a limit >0

Comment: @MaxPierini I modified the bounds of some variables as your comment, and now it works! Thanks a lot! :)